# Changing a mode's keymap for the duration of a command's execution

Tags: keymap, company-mode, dynamic-scoping

I would like to bind `TAB` to my company-mode back-end only for the duration of a command's execution. I am trying to achieve this by using dynamic scoping as follows (the irrelevant part of the function is not shown):

```
(defun my-function()
  (interactive)
  (let ((company-mode-map (copy-sequence company-mode-map)))
    (define-key company-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-company-backend)
    MORE-CODE-HERE))
```

The new binding does not work (though it did work when I performed it outside of `my-function`). Why does this use of dynamic scoping not produce the result that I expected and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment you wrote on of the other answers was very useful in
figuring out what you want to do; I hope I understood correctly. I
believe you want to write a command that prompts for a string from the
minibuffer with TAB temporarily bound to `my-company-backend.

Assuming the string prompted for is the only argument your command
needs, try something like this:

```
(defun my-function (my-arg)
  (interactive
   (let ((minibuffer-local-map (copy-sequence minibuffer-local-map)))
     (define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-company-backend)
     (list (read-string "Prompt: " "default string"))))
  MORE-CODE-HERE) ; here my-arg will hold the string the user typed
```

Comment: This works! However, I think that I have discovered a bug in company mode: https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/690

Answer (score 0):

Inside the backend function? Why? The function will return before the user's next input is processed.

You can change `company-active-map`, though.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. As for the suggestion, I will look into using active maps, but would still appreciate if you provide a code snippet.

Comment: `company-active-map` is the name of a global variable.

Comment: But then we are back to the problem that I started with! Namely, I want to make sure that the active map gets restored once my function is done. That is the reason I used `let` in the first place...

Comment: When is your function *done*?

Comment: The function is a command. It is done either when it exits with a value, or an error happens, or the user stops it by pressing C-g. I want to use dynamic scoping to be safe in any case. That is, I want the keymap with `TAB` bound to my back-end to exist only locally inside `let` and the functions called by my command. I have edited the question to make all this clearer.

Comment: But keymap only takes effect between commands, doesn't it? Aside from the scenario where your code takes over the input loop for a while, but then I'm not sure why you'd want to change the current keymap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
(cl-letf (((current-local-map) (make-sparse-keymap)))
  ...)
```

But, like mentioned in the comment, I doubt the utility of this.

Comment: May be I am missing something. I have a command, which takes input from mini-buffer. It puts the mini-buffer in company-mode to have completion from a list of keywords. For that input (and *only* for that input) I want the `TAB` key to be bound to my company mode back-end. If the user opens some other buffer in company mode, there should not be any trace of my binding, i.e. `TAB` should be unbound. So, when you doubt the utility of this, I am thinking that I must be missing something conceptual about Emacs. I will very much appreciate if you correct my mistake.

Comment: You'll need to change the local map of the minibuffer's buffer. Usually that's done in `minibuffer-setup-hook`. See `icomplete-minibuffer-setup` as one example of such hook (it calls `use-local-map`).

Comment: But that will affect any command that uses mini-buffer. If I did not care about that, I could evaluate `define-key` outside of my command (which is what I used to do and it worked). I am looking for a clean solution, whereby the change of key binding is totally encapsulated inside my command and does not affect any other code.

Comment: You will bind `minibuffer-setup-hook` temporarily, only inside your function.